# How to adapt changes among different bootstrap css files

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a code I post below. The problem is that the toggle collapse function works when I use bootstrap version 3.3.5, and it fails with 4.1.3 or other higher versions. The thing is that I need to use 4.1.3 and would like to keep the toggle capability as well. I believe the solution must be trivial.
How can I use it?

```
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.level1 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.level2 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.collapse .toggle {
    background: url("http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/images/collapse.gif");
}
.expand .toggle {
    background: url("http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/images/expand.gif");
}
.toggle {
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
</style>

<form method="post" id="iddetailForm" name="detailForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table width="900" id="mytable">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
<tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0" bgcolor="#45ADF7">
    <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span> Names</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>500</td>
</tr>
<tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1" bgcolor="#93CEF7">
    <td><span class="toggle"></span> name1</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1" bgcolor="#93CEF7">
    <td><span class="toggle"></span> name2</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>200</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#mytable').on('click', '.toggle', function () {
        var findChildren = function (tr) {
        var depth = tr.data('depth');
        return tr.nextUntil($('tr').filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('depth') <= depth;
        }));
    };

    var el = $(this);
    var tr = el.closest('tr'); //Get <tr> parent of toggle button
    var children = findChildren(tr);

    var subnodes = children.filter('.expand');
    subnodes.each(function () {
        var subnode = $(this);
        var subnodeChildren = findChildren(subnode);
        children = children.not(subnodeChildren);
    });

    //Change icon and hide/show children
    if (tr.hasClass('collapse')) {
        tr.removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
        children.hide();
    } else {
        tr.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
        children.show();
    }
    return children;
});
 $('.toggle').click();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your style the !important tag so it will not be overwritten:

```
<style>
.level1 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 10px!important;
}
.level2 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 20px!important;
}

.collapse .toggle {
    background: url("http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/images/collapse.gif")!important;
}
.expand .toggle {
    background: url("http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/images/expand.gif")!important;
}
.toggle {
    height: 9px!important;
    width: 9px!important;
    display: inline-block!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works but the expand disappears now. How can I fix it?

Comment: collapse row disappears when you click on it(

Comment: that was because of collapse, O renamed them it worked.

Comment: @Nessi Maybe you can share the changes you made as well in case people have the same problem. ;)